# how to send $form object from view to $this->renderpartial() view in yii1?

Tags: php, yii

Can I send $form object from a view file to another view file called from renderPartial???

```
like :: $this->renderPartial("eventTiming",array('form'=>$form,');
```

Actually I want to divide my code into group of renderpartial html code.

Thanks

Comment: Yea I don't see why now. You can send it as far as you'd like but keep in mind that `$this` refers to the controller from which you send it initially. So if you want to use that form in the same action that treated it firstly it will be fine. No sure what you're trying to accomplish but that is how you do it. I usually have a general content view with multiple `$this->renderPartial()` and send stuff to multiple partial view files.

Comment: Also you have a typos, this should looks like `$this->renderPartial("eventTiming", array('form'=>$form));`